# Exploding a string, then inserting resulting array back into array

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array like so:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => {#472 ▼
    +"component_id": 3
    +"supplier_id": 1
    +"volumes": "100:1.5000,207:1.0100,500:0.8000,1000:0.4000"
  }
  1 => {#474 ▼
    +"component_id": 3
    +"supplier_id": 2
    +"volumes": "10000:0.2000"
  }
  2 => {#475 ▼
    +"component_id": 4
    +"supplier_id": 2
    +"volumes": "100:0.1000,500:0.0700"
  }
]
```

I want to explode the 'volumes' part and create it's own array out of it, ending up like so:

```
[
    "component_id" => 4
    "supplier_id" => 2
    "volumes" => array:3 [▼
        100 => "0.1000",
        500 => "0.0700"
    ]
]
```

I've tried a few things, and this is closest I've got so far (n.b. using Laravel 5.2):

```
$components = DB::select(
                'SELECT component_id, supplier_id,
                GROUP_CONCAT(volume, \':\', unit_cost) AS volumes
                FROM component_supplier
                GROUP BY CONCAT(component_id, supplier_id)'
                );

        foreach ($components as $component) {
            $exploded = explode(",",$component->volumes);
            array_push($components, $exploded);
        }
```

Which is closer! But just appends the sort-of correct format onto the end of the array - which is what I would expect from array_push I guess :)

```
array:6 [▼
  0 => {#472 ▼
    +"component_id": 3
    +"supplier_id": 1
    +"volumes": "100:1.5000,207:1.0100,500:0.8000,1000:0.4000"
  }
  1 => {#474 ▼
    +"component_id": 3
    +"supplier_id": 2
    +"volumes": "10000:0.2000"
  }
  2 => {#475 ▼
    +"component_id": 4
    +"supplier_id": 2
    +"volumes": "100:0.1000,500:0.0700"
  }
  3 => array:4 [▼
    0 => "100:1.5000"
    1 => "207:1.0100"
    2 => "500:0.8000"
    3 => "1000:0.4000"
  ]
  4 => array:1 [▼
    0 => "10000:0.2000"
  ]
  5 => array:2 [▼
    0 => "100:0.1000"
    1 => "500:0.0700"
  ]
]
```

So I'm struggling to explode it, get it into a key => value format, and then (most importantly), push it back into the array at the correct point.

Thank you for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($components as $component) {
    $volumesList = explode(',', $component->volumes);
    $volumesDictionary = [];
    foreach ($volumesList as $listItem) {
        list($key, $value) = explode(':', $listItem);
        $volumesDictionary[$key] = $value;
    }
    $component->volumes = $volumesDictionary;
}
```

Explanation:
Items are separated by commas, key-value pairs are separated by colons. So we have to explode twice. Having keys separated from values, we add them to a dictionary. Finally, we want to replace the serialized dictionary with an associative array, so instead of calling `array_push` (which always appends items to the end of an array, *not* to items to the last item *in* the array) we just replace `$component->volumes` string with the newly created dictionary.

Comment: Thanks Mad Dog for the explanation and sample code, this is really helpful and informative.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need two explodes. Something like this.

```
  foreach ($components as $component) {

        $exploded = explode(",",$component->volumes);

        foreach($exploded as $item)
        {
            $ex_item = explode(':', $item);
            $components[$ex_item[0]] = $ex_item[1];
        }
    }
```